# What is considered a normal number of concurrent login for Azure SQL Database?

Tags: sql, database, azure

I'm new to Azure SQL Database as this is my first project to migrate from a on premise setup to everything on Azure. So the first thing that got my concern is that there is a limit on concurrent login to the Azure SQL Database, and if it exist that number, then it'll start dropping the subsequent request. For the current service tier (S0), it caps at 60 concurrent logins, which I have already reached multiple times as I've encountered a few SQL failures from looking at my application log.

So my question is:
Is it normal to exceed that number of concurrent login? I'd like to get an idea of whether or not my application is having some issue, or my current service tier is too low.

I've looked into our database code to make sure we are not leaving database connection open. We use Enterprise Library, every use of DBCommand and IDataReader are being wrapped within a using block, thus they will get disposed once it runs out of scope.

Note: my web application consists of a front end app with multiple web services supporting the underlying feature, and each service will connect to the same database for specific collection of data, which makes me think hitting 60 concurrent login might be normal since a page or an action might involve multiple calls behind the scene, thus multiple connection to the database from a few api, and if there are more than one user on the application, then 60 is really easy to reach.

Again, in the past with on prem setup, I never notice this kind of limitation.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you using connection pooling? Also I don't consider `S0` to be for production use unless it's a very limited, simple application.

Comment: Yea, I have the same feeling 60 seems to be very little. It's just we never have to worry about the login limit when we have our actual sql database server. And to answer you question, it's not a simple application.

The support engineer from MS told me it's not normal to reach the 60 limit...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your question, the limit is 60 on an S(0)

[image]

http://gavinstevens.com/2016/11/30/sql-server-vs-azure-sql/

Comment: I know the limit per service tier, my question is, if it's normal for a production app to reach that count easily.

Comment: That's really hard to say, it depends a lot on how the code is written, not on the database itself.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-resource-limits